# Disable linter error of `method is not a known member of module "cv2"` from pylance in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance, linter

- OS: WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- VSCode version: 1.85.2
- Pylance version: v2023.12.1
- Pyhotn version: 3.10.13
- opencv-python version: 4.6.0.66
- settings.json

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Ubuntu (WSL)",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro",
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "flake8.args":[
        "--ignore=W293,W292,W291",
    ],
    "pylint.args":[
        "--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2",
        "--generated-members=numpy.*, torch.*, cv2.*,  cv.*",
        "--disable=C0114,C0115,C0116"
    ],
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",  // Pylance
    "python.analysis.fixAll": [],
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Monokai",
    "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "Monokai",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
    },
    "editor.rulers": [
        79
    ],
    "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "192.168.60.229": "linux",
        "192.168.60.230": "linux"
    },
    "githubPullRequests.pullBranch": "never",
    "vim.useCtrlKeys": false,
    "workbench.tree.indent": 4,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "isort.check": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "remote.autoForwardPortsSource": "hybrid",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.md": "default"
    },
    "markdown-preview-enhanced.previewTheme": "atom-dark.css",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never"
}
```

I have installed the pylance, pylint and flake8 extensions with configuring settings with `cv2` yet it shows the linter error message `"cvtColor" is not a known member of module "cv2"`. Could anyone help me with this linter setting problem? many thanks!
[image]